# shmat() - invalid argument

Tags: c, shared-memory

I´m having some trouble, trying to read the shmem.
The program writing the data is giving me no error so i don't know what to do anymore.

```
typedef struct
{
    long id;
} data;

data *dados[MAX];

int main()
{
    key_t key = 5678;
    int shmid;

    if (shmid = shmget(key, MAX * sizeof(data),0666) < 0)
    {
        perror("shmget error");
        return 1;
    }

    if((*dados = shmat(shmid,NULL,0)) == (void*) -1){
        perror("shmat");
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("time:%ld\n", dados[i]->id);
        printf("passed %d",i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (shmid = shmget(key, MAX * sizeof(data),0666) < 0)` -> `if ((shmid = shmget(key, MAX * sizeof(data),0666)) < 0)`. This is because `<` has higher precedence than `=`.

Comment: `data` is not defined

Comment: ```typedef struct
{
    long id;
} data;```

Comment: ***Don't cram the assignment into the `if` statement!!!***  I hate shouting, but questions with this bug get posted over and over here.  There's a reason why ***assignments in `if` statements are forbidden by code standard*** in organizations that actually care about preventing the creation of bugs.  `int shmid = shmget(key, MAX * sizeof(data),0666);` and then `if ( shmid < 0 )` ***on the next line*** completely avoids this bug.  Cramming the assignment into the `if` statement is bug-prone and ***BAD CODE***.  Anyone saying otherwise doesn't care about bug-avoidance - ***ignore them***.

Comment: And the reason you couldn't see the bug is because human brains can only make associations between and/or keep track of a very small number of things at any one time - the number is usually in the range of 3-7.  When you do something like cram the assignment into the `if` statement you wind up using 3 of them with just that one operation, leaving little to no brain capacity for spotting the precedence issue.  Run far away from the "brevity of code" cargo cult - they taught you a style that literally caused this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (shmid = shmget(key, MAX * sizeof(data),0666) < 0)
```

According to [C operator order of precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) the `<` operator has higher precedence than the `=` operator. Thus the above code actually assigns the boolean `shmget(key, MAX * sizeof(data),0666) < 0` result to `shmid`.

Use explicit bracketing to get the desired result:

```
if ((shmid = shmget(key, MAX * sizeof(data),0666)) < 0)
```